# weird internet explorer 6 problem css

Tags: html, css

hello i have a div and background image attached to its top. here i get this result for modern browsers: http://i52.tinypic.com/29ckkt4.jpg

but when comes to ie6 i get this result

http://i53.tinypic.com/30m8m05.jpg

applied css code is     #top {
    background: url(../images/cpmtenttop-trans.png) repeat-x top left; height:22px;
}

Comment: post your code in jsfiddle.com so we can see. Also change top left to "0 0". You know IE 6 has no native transparent png support right? you might want to use http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ IE8.js

Comment: This is so off topic, that I can't even categorize it as an answer to your question, so I'll make it a comment. FYI, Microsoft is in the process of encouraging the world to kill IE6. They just recently launched this site: http://ie6countdown.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's because of PNG format. Checkout this page:
http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/

Comment: @Susan, Are they all background-image? Because I had the same issue before just for background images.

Comment: yes, i'm using this IE8.js which cover png problems for backgrounds also.

Comment: This link might help you: http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2007/11/css-png-image-fix-for-ie/